# What is causing my "Unexpected EOF Error while looking for ..." error?

Tags: bash, cron

I am getting an issue while running a cron job for exporting all databases on my Godaddy Shared hosting Cpanel account. But I have trouble finding the syntax error in below command.

Same command is working on my AWS Ec2.

```
mysql -N -ubackup -pt -e 'show databases' | while read dbname; do mysqldump -ubackup -p123 --complete-insert -N "$dbname" > /home/test/sqlbackups/'$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")-$dbname'.sql;done
```

Error Received on Mail:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: There are no unmatched single quotes in that line. The only problem is the quoting of the `$(...)`, but that's not a syntax error...

Comment: If it's in a crontab entry, you need to escape the `%` with backslash (and also fix your quoting issue as already pointed out).

Comment: See [How can I execute \`date\` inside of a cron tab job?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/29578)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crontab commands will have all unescaped occurrences of `%` replaced by newlines. This is from [the `crontab(5)` manual](http://man.openbsd.org/crontab.5) on my system:

> The command field (the rest of the line) is the command to be run.  The
>        entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or `%` character, will
>        be executed by `/bin/sh` or by the shell specified in the `SHELL` variable of
>        the crontab.  **Percent signs (`%`) in the command, unless escaped with a
>        backslash (`\`), will be changed into newline characters, and all data
>        after the first `%` will be sent to the command as standard input.**

Your crontab command should look like

```
mysql -N -ubackup -pt -e 'show databases' | while read dbname; do mysqldump -ubackup -p123 --complete-insert -N "$dbname" > /home/test/sqlbackups/"$(date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d")-$dbname".sql;done
```

Here, I've also corrected the `$(...)` that was previously single-quoted (and thus not expanded by the shell).

In general, it's better to put all non-trivial cron jobs in their own scripts and then schedule these instead.  That way you have more control over things like this and you are also able to choose the correct interpreter for any particular job (e.g. `ksh` or `bash` instead of `sh`). It additionally makes any subject lines in emails sent to you from the cron daemon more readable.

Comment: Using scripts instead of long command lines in cron jobs also makes the subject of emails you get about them failing more legible

Comment: Thanks it works. I will keep it mind while adding date formats in future.